# Creating mongodb collection automatically with only one document?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I need to have a page with common settings for my web-app, and using mongodb as my database.

I am planning to just create this collection with only one document. it will always have one document.

Is there a way to create one document by default in some way? and then just edit it from UI?

Or I should create one document from UI itself and then keep editing it?

If I use config file then user won't have flexibility of changing the value as they need.

Please share if you have better suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly have a collection with a single document in it.

> Is there a way to create one document by default in some way?

You can insert the document with default values, if there isn't already a document in the collection, when your application starts.